# Training gensim doc2vec occures memory error?

Tags: word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I want to train doc2vec model by gensim but my corpus is too large. 
Is there any method to train every batch of sentences corpus? For example, iterately load some corpus and train the model on it, and reload another batch of corpus....

I don't know if there is any api or method for doing this. Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

How many unique words/doc-tags are in your corpus, and `size` dimensions in your model?

Those values contribute to the irreducible necessary size of your model, that must fit into addressable memory.

How are you supplying your corpus to `Doc2Vec`?

It *can* take an restartable iterable object that streams text examples from disk, so the full corpus need not be in memory. So if that's your problem, a better corpus-iterable, that returns TaggedDocuments, may solve your memory problem.

See https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/ for more on making a proper iterable object.